# Why does rounding POSIXct change ability to match equivalent POSIXct?

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

Can someone explain to me why the following POSIXct time elements don't 'match'?

I'm ultimately trying to match the datetime values in vector `time` to those in vector `datetime`. I've simplified the example so that everything is the same date and only the hour values differ. In this example, I can use `match` to find the index position of each `time` in `datetime`. However if I need to round my datetimes in `time` to the nearest hour, given here as `roundtime` suddenly the match fails? But `time==roundtime` ? What am I missing here?

```
datetime <- as.POSIXct("2020-01-01 15:00:00",tz="UTC") + (0:10) * 3600
time <- as.POSIXct(c("2020-01-01 15:00:00", "2020-01-01 16:00:00", "2020-01-01 21:00:00"),tz='UTC')
roundtime<-round(time,units="hours")

time %in% datetime # gives TRUES
time %in% roundtime # give FALSES?
time == roundtime # gives TRUES
match(time, datetime) # returns matches
match(time, roundtime) # No matches?
match(roundtime, datetime) # no matches?
```

Comment: I suspect this is related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/3358272, https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f, since underneath, a `POSIXt` object is just a floating-point number.

Comment: Also, note that `class(roundtime)` gives `[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"` - so it is a `list` of `list`s, whereas `datetime` etc are vectors.

Comment: @Limey ... that (`POSIXlt`) is a huge thing, I didn't realize that `round.POSIXt` was broken in that way. Granted, it's easy to fix, but ... geez ... that's horrible. Almost as bad (in my opinion) as `ifelse` not being class-safe.

Comment: That `base:::round.POSIXt` throws `POSIXlt` is documented. Use `roundtime <- round(time, units="hours") |> as.POSIXct()`.

Comment: @r2evans  Agreed.  On reflection, I think the issue deserves more than a simple comment, so I've provided an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer expands on my comment to OP's original question.

The problem appears to be down to a silent class change caused by the use of `round`:

```
class(time)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
class(datetime)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

but

```
class(roundtime)
[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"
```

The class change is performed without warning or note and is hidden by the default S3 `print` methods:

```
print(datetime[1])
[1] "2020-01-01 15:00:00 UTC"
print(time[1])
[1] "2020-01-01 15:00:00 UTC"
print(roundtime[1])
[1] "2020-01-01 15:00:00 UTC"
```

However, it's obvious when the objects are `unclass`ed:

```
print(unclass(datetime[1]))
[1] 1577890800
attr(,"tzone")
[1] "UTC"
print(unclass(time[1]))
[1] 1577890800
attr(,"tzone")
[1] "UTC"
print(unclass(roundtime[1]))
$sec
[1] 0

$min
[1] 0

$hour
[1] 15

$mday
[1] 1

$mon
[1] 0

$year
[1] 120

$wday
[1] 3

$yday
[1] 0

$isdst
[1] 0

attr(,"tzone")
[1] "UTC"
```

`match` appears to fail (although it is actually working correctly) because, as is made clear in its online documentation, "Factors, raw vectors and lists are converted to character vectors, internally classed objects are transformed via mtfrm, and then x and table are coerced to a common type (the later of the two types in R's ordering, logical < integer < numeric < complex < character) before matching. ... Exactly what matches what is to some extent a matter of definition".

The problem can be avoided by using `lubridate` (and, as an additional benefit, I think the relevant function names make the programmer's intention far more transparent):

```
library(lubridate)
roundtime1 <- floor_date(datetime, "hour")
class(roundtime1)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
match(time, roundtime1)
[1] 1 2 7
match(roundtime1, datetime)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

As @r2evans writes, this is a silent, nasty, gotcha that (whilst documented and easily fixed) can lead to unexpected behaviour that is difficult to identify and avoid.

Comment: thank you for the very clear answer! I totally missed that class change.